# Uploading Video on twitter using HTTP API

Tags: java, android, api, twitter, twitter4j

Hi I am trying to upload Video using REST APIs of twitter [Twitter POST video Request](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked)

In this documentation, I am not able to understand how can I make this command from my Android Code.:

```
twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -d "command=INIT&media_type=video/mp4&total_bytes=4430752"
```

Also, I am able to post status updates and images using twitter4j, do I need to reAuthenticate to use HTTP APIs:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
            Date date = new Date();
            String status = date.toString();
            Log.d("Status", status);
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate("@UserName : " +status);
                if(((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getLinkPath() != null) { //getting image resource file
                    String s = "file://" + ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getLinkPath();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
                    InputStream is = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Log.d("Logger", "Sending media");
                    statusUpdate.setMedia(s, is);
                    Log.d(s, "Sent media");

                }
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);

                Log.d("Status", response.getText());

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("Failed to post!", e.getMessage());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what your command does.

Comment: Using the chunked POST media/upload endpoint requires an adjusted workflow from single image uploads. For video or chunked uploads, you must:

Initialize the upload using the INIT command
That is what the command for. For more commands refer https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#chunkedupload

Comment: any example of chunkedupload video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 03/16/2018, New PR and Maven Repo

I created a pull request to add this feature in twitter4j.  You can look at the implementation here:
[Adding Chuncked, video upload](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/pull/255)

Comment: Looks like it was accepted but there is some more work to be done on it.

Comment: any example about?

Comment: This is a old PR.  I update the PR to support full async upload of large video files 512mb and 140sec.  https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/pull/255

Comment: Not accepted but I created a Maven repo if anyone wants this branch.

Comment: The pull request was accepted.  It's now part of the official release.